# VBA macro to overwrite data from one table to another

Tags: vba, excel

If you have 2 workbooks called `Workbook1` and `Workbook2` and each have identical tables (in terms of columns) called `reference_table` and you want to update the `reference_table` of `Workbook 2` from that of `Workbook 1`, how would you write a macro that completely overwrites the `reference_table` in `Workbook 2`?

The reason a complete overwrite is needed is because the new `refernce_table` could be smaller than the one needing to be updated.

So far I have been adapting code, but I don't know how to interact with tables.

```
Sub Overwrite()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim fldBase As Folder
    Dim fWb As File

    Dim wsOrigin As Worksheet
    Dim newData As Name
    Dim newRng As Range

    Dim refWb As Worksheet
    Dim oldData As Name
    Dim oldRng As Range

    'Get current version of Table1
    Set wsOrigin = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<-- adjust to your ws name in Dashboard
    Set newData = wsOrigin.Names("Table1") '<-- Origin table name
    Set newRng = newData.RefersToRange

    'Set current workbooks file location as base
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fldBase = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)

    For Each fWb In fldBase.Files
        If fWb.Name = "Worksheet2.xls*" Then

            'Open Worksheet that needs upodating
            Set refWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fWb.Path, ReadOnly:=False)
            Set oldData = refWb.Names("Table1") '<-- Table name
            Set oldRng = oldData.RefersToRange

            'Old data removed
            oldData.DataBodyRange.Delete

            'Add new data
            oldRng = newRng.Value

            'Close and save updated file
            'refWb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possible should read [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

For your poblem this might help

```
Sub CopyToWks(wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet, tblName As String)

    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Dim tbl2 As ListObject
    Dim rg As Range

    Set tbl1 = wks1.ListObjects(tblName)
    Set rg = tbl1.Range

    Set tbl2 = wks2.ListObjects(tblName)
    tbl2.Delete

    rg.Copy wks2.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

A test could look like that

```
Sub testIt()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wks1 As Worksheet
Dim wks2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("WB1.XLSM")
    Set wks1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("WB2.XLSM")
    Set wks2 = wb2.Sheets(1)

    CopyToWks wks1, wks2, "Table1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the link it is indeed pretty much a lot of what I need to learn, and also thank you for the example, this works well when both worksheets are open. Now I just have to make it work so that it opens `Workbook2` and performs the code.

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure both workbooks are open. You could use `Workbooks.open` for that as you do in the code you posted. So I assume, you are familiar how to do that.

Comment: I am to a degree, you could say I am punching above my weight while on a learning curve :). But yes, I think I can hack that together from here, I just need to use FSO to ensure that it opens the other workbook from the same folder in which the current workbook is.